# using regex to replace a match in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to use `String.replace()` with a regular expression to replace a matched expression.

Like so:

`var newStr =  loc.replace(/Slide(\d*)/,(i+1));`

This expression turns

`https://xxxxxxx.net/qa/club/Slide1.PNG`

into

`https://xxxxxxx.net/qa/club/1.PNG`

I just want to replace the numbers after "Slide", without removing the word. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it always "Slide" that you want to remove?

Comment: @JHuangweb I never want to remove "Slide"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capture group and insert it in your replacement.

```
loc.replace(/(Slide)\d*/, '$1' + (i+1));
```

If the word will always be slide, then you can simply use this without capturing anything

```
loc.replace(/Slide\d*/, 'Slide' + (i+1));
```

The paratheses around (i + 1) are important to force the mathematical operation before string concatenation.

If `Slide` is always followed by a number, change the `*` to a `+` in the regular expression.

Comment: I don't want `Slide` at all. I just want the number. The `+` seems to Match `Slide` in addition to the number.